# schroot: Configuration key name 'file' is not a permitted name

Tags: debian, chroot, schroot

I'm trying to configure a `file chroot`, following the "man" documentation. According to the manpage of `schroot`, I can use a filesystem tree archive file, and the configure an schroot to use that archive as file system. For example, in /etc/schroot.conf, the following example exists:

```
#[lenny-file]
#description=Debian lenny (oldstable)
#file=/srv/chroot/lenny.tar.gz
#location=/lenny
#groups=sbuild
```

So I changed it a little to:

```
[stretch-file]
description=Debian Stretch
file=/tmp/jail.tar
location=/jail
groups=sbuild
```

Of course, `/tmp/jail.tar` exists, and contains minimal bootsrapped stretch.

When trying to enter the chroot with `schroot -c chroot:stretch-file` I get the following warning:

```
W: line 77 [stretch-file]: Obsolete key ‘location’ used
I: This option has been removed, and no longer has any effect
W: line 76 [stretch-file] file: Configuration key name ‘file’ is not a permitted name.
```

I thing that the interesting line is `Configuration key name ‘file’ is not a permitted name.` - How can it be? Is the man page wrong? Or do I do anything in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

The missing link in the configuration in the question is the key `type=`. That means that the configuration should have looked like this:

```
[stretch-file]
description=Debian Stretch
type=file
file=/tmp/jail.tar
location=/jail
groups=sbuild
```

For some reason, the examples in the `/etc/schroot/schroot.conf` failed to contain that key.